# Prevent commas in CSV file from defining a new column when generating CSV

Tags: csv

Example $this->generating_csv = "12,000".",";

instead of insert 12,000 in one column is inserting 12 in first and 000 in second column.

how can i solve this (php)

Comment: Replace `,` with another, non-separating character.

Comment: Try adding a backslash? Seriously, you don't even say what language you're using so how are we supposed to even have an idea?

Comment: That's what CSV _means_ - **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the reading program's fault, if you are quoting the fields.

But it looks like you aren't quoting the fields.

[RFC4180](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) allows for a line in a CSV file like:

```
"A","12,000","C"
```

to be 3 fields, not 4 fields. Notice that the fields are quoted.

```
A,12,000,C
```

is 4 fields, with `A` for field 1, `12` for field 2, `000` for field 3, and `C` for field 4.  The reading program can't read this any other way... it can't read minds.

But many programs can not deal with a CSV file with commas in fields, even when the fields are correctly quoted so that they may include a comma. Adding to the confusion, many programs can be set up to split on comma rather than read according to RFC4180. Splitting on comma is not sufficient to read the full RFC4180 CSV format.

That being said, there is another problem here:  `12,000` is not a valid number in Python, Javascript, R, and many languages, so even if the program is using a good RFC4180 reader (e.g. the `csv` module in python), changing the `12,000` into a number will still fail.

So possibly you want to remove commas between digits in quoted fields.

In your case, since you are generating the CSV file in PHP, simply
try these two approaches:

Alternative A: Quote the fields

```
$this->generating_csv = '"12,000"'.','.'"field2"'
```

This will cause the `"` to appear in the output

Alternative B: generate the field without the extra comma:

```
$this->generating_csv = "12000".","."field2"
```

If you already have several CSV files with commas in quoted fields and the reading program will not read them correctly, you can search/replace using a regexp to clean out the commas. In Python the following will clean up commas in a csv file:

```
import csv
import sys
import re
infile = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
outfile = open(sys.argv[2],'w')
csvin = csv.reader(infile)
csvout = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for rowin in csvin:
    rowout = []
    for origfield in rowin:
        field = origfield[1:-1] if origfield[0:1]=='"' else origfield
        # change 10,000 to 10000
        field = re.sub(r'(\d+),(\d+)', r'\1\2', field)
        # change Cleveland, OH to Cleveland OH
        field = field.replace(r',',r' ')
        rowout.append(field)
    csvout.writerow(rowout)
```